# White screen for 10.12.2 upgrade on mac mini

Tags: upgrade, mac-mini

When I try to upgrade to 10.12.2, my mac mini reboots to a white screen. The mouse is responsive, but nothing is drawn. In previous upgrades, I could get past this by holding SHIFT for safe mode; and then the upgrade would complete. Not this time. There are no USB devices except the keyboard plugged in. I've reset PRAM/NVRAM, no change. I can boot to recovery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Which Mac mini model are you using? Did also try another video connection port e.g Thunderbolt or HDMI? Is happening on a clean OS X installation?

Comment: Does Safe boot get you to a login screen at all? If so, can you get into a different admin account than your usual one? Might be similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264863/security-update-2016-003-10-11-6-issues if so.

Comment: No login screen. No change when using HDMI instead of thunderbolt/dvi.

Comment: Same symptoms, but no little snitch and no relief via safe mode. Restored from time machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same white screen issue after updating to 10.12.2 and was forced to restore from a previous time machine backup (after trying to repair the drive, resetting the PRAM/NVRAM and booting safe mode failed to work).  Stupidly, I tried updating to 10.12.2 again on the restored version and during the reboot process it went back to the white screen.

Don't install 10.12.2 if you have this issue.